# How to get DOM from html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display my html file in the preview. Basically when I open my html file from my application file menu "open", I need my whole html file contents to be displayed on the tool's preview using javascript.How to do this?

Comment: Far too many unknowns to even attempt to interpret this question without a lot of guessing. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i completely understand the question but I hope this example help you start.
you can try this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a BODY element</h3>

<p>Click the button to set the background color of the document to red.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```